# How to update HTML element with jQuery and Galleria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, galleria

I am using Galleria for a slideshow. I want to place a small, 'Larger' link beside the `stage`.

I have this code for the 'Larger' button:

```
this.fullres = this.create('div', 'fullres');
this.get('fullres').innerHTML = '<a href="#">Larger</a>';
this.appendChild('fullres', this.fullres);
```

I have this code that assigns every `<img>`'s `rel=` tag to the full sized image URL from the page's custom field:

```
<img ... rel="<?=$attachments[$i]['fullres']?>" />
```

With JQuery, I am hoping to pull the `active` image's `rel=` tag value and append the `.fullres href` tag. This is the code I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
var title = $(.images).attr('rel'); // pulls the fullres url from the rel tag
$('.galleria-fullres').attr('href', ); //append the galleria fullres href with the rel info
```

Comment: how are you getting a reference to the active image? does it have class active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galleria doesn't really work like that. But what you can do, is to create a button to enter fullscreen and have a larger image in fullscreen.

Something like this:

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    // other galleria options here
    dataConfig: function( img ) {
        // get the fullscreen image
        return {
            big: $( img ).attr('rel')
        };
    }
});

var galleria = Galleria.get(0);

$('#fullscreen-button').click(function() {
    galleria.enterFullscreen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I can't see how this would work as it is...

Do you know you have a typo at: `$(.images)`? Should be `$('.images')`.

And have you left out the second parameter at `$('.galleria-fullres').attr('href', );` on purpose? Shouldn't this be `$('.galleria-fullres').attr('href', title);` ?

How can the jquery work by referencing the elements by classes? You are getting an array of elements, not just one.  I guess this is only an excerpt of your code? Am I missing something?

Could you perhaps post the html of a sample of these elements as seen in the browser? It should be a pretty easy thing, but I really can't see the whole picture with those lines only.